# Angular ng-table sorting not working in fixed header

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am very new to Angularjs. I have created an table using ng-table, The problem is the table header sorting is not working.

Sample code attached here.

HTML : (Sample ng-table)

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>Row 1</tr>
        <tr>Row 2</tr>
        <tr>Row 3</tr>
        <tr>Row 4</tr>
        <tr>Row 5</tr>
        <tr>Row 6</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td sortable="'value1'">{{user.value1}}</td>
            <td sortable="'value2'">{{user.value2}}</td>
            <td sortable="'value3'">{{user.value3}}</td>
            <td sortable="'value4'">{{user.value4}}</td>
            <td sortable="'value5'">{{user.value5}}</td>
            <td sortable="'value6'">{{user.value6}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller :

```
    $http.get('/portal/api/documents/'+Id).success(function(data){
            var data = data.result;
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,           // count per page
                sorting: {
                    name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                }
            }, {
                total: data.length, // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                  // Pagination
                  $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                   // use build-in angular filter
                    var orderedData = params.sorting ?
                            $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                            data;

                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem comes from your sorting configuration :

```
sorting: {
   name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
}
```

You seem not to have a `name` parameter in one of your table column (value1, value2, ... unless you didn't show us your real code)

If you want to sort your first column, you should try this :

```
sorting: {
   value1: 'asc'     // initial sorting
}
```

Comment: Could you precise what is not working ? 
Your data are not orderred on a special column (`value1` like in my answer) ? 
You do not have the arrows in the column headers to choose the sort ?

Comment: I didn't test that but comparing with the ngTable example [link](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/2-1) you should try set this : 
1. Removing your `thead` content 
2. Adding instead the `data-title` attribute in the `<td>` tag :  `<td data-title="'Row 1'" sortable="'value1'">`

Comment: Ok nice. Could you validate my answer please. Thanks.